# Accessing properties of user's action with an apprequest on iOS

Tags: dialog, fbconnect, apprequests, facebook-ios-sdk

I was hoping the FBDialog returned to dialogDidComplete would hold information about what the user did with the dialog. Specifically, if the dialog was to invite the user's friends to the app I'd like to keep track of how many friends or which friends the invite was sent to. It'd be nice to track how effective (or not) the virality actions are. Is there anyway to access what the user did with the dialog in more detail?